# Why the background color does not change when I move focus away from a list view?

Tags: android, listview, background, selector

I have a layout like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu                  |    Content                                                 |
|This is a ListView     |    This is a ListView                                      |
|                       |                                                            |
| Menu 1                |    Content 1                                               |
| Menu 2                |    Content 2                                               |
| Menu 3                |    Content 3                                               |
| Menu 4                |    Content 4                                               |
|                       |    Content 5                                               |
|                       |    Content 6                                               |
```

The layout file of item is(**update: Simplified**):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/selector_list_item"
    />
```

As you can see I set the background `selector_list_item`, this selector is something like this:

**updated: Thanks to @Kelevandos remind, I rewrite my selector and add more chages.**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

Due to my **platform is a TV**, so I use the state `state_selected=true`.(**updated: I tried to add more state, but in fact only `stated_selected` is used in project.**)

**So here is the problem**, when I move in `Content` view, the color will change in list view, but when I move away from `Content` view to `Menu` view, the `Content` view background will not change to `white`.

BTW, when I remove `android:background="@drawable/selector_list_item"`, the default color change normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the state you are using. Just change

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

to

```
<item 
android:state_selected="true"
android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
```

and it should work as intended :-)

As a side note, it is a general practice to put the drawable part **after** the state values.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding me. My platform is a TV, so I have no `state_pressed`(also I tried just now, it didn't work as I say). I don't know the thing that the `Menu` and `Content` is included in a `HorizontalScrollView` matter.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I just learn android recently. But your method seems doesn't work.

Comment: And I just change the `HorizontalScrollView` to `LinerayLayout`, the problems still exists.

Comment: I think I do know where is the problem, the code has different performance in different android platforms. I have reopen a problem, if you are interested in, please check.[Different performance of ListView in Android 4.4.4 and Android 4.2.2, how to remain the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602788/different-performance-of-listview-in-android-4-4-4-and-android-4-2-2-how-to-rem)