# How to clear selection of ListView when the ListView lose focus and reset the old selection when the ListView has focus?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Recently, I am working in a TV platform, I find that when I move from one `ListView` to some other view, the `ListView` will keep the selection which makes the `ListView` background doesn't change(I have asked the background problem at [Why the background color does not change when I move focus away from a list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597999/why-the-background-color-does-not-change-when-i-move-focus-away-from-a-list-view)).

I think if I clear the selection when I move away from the `ListView`, the background will set to normal, so I add these code:

```
mMenuView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            mMenuView.clearChoices();
            mMenuView.setItemChecked(mMenuView.getSelectedItemPosition(), false);
        }
    }
});
```

But, it seems that I do not clear the selection successfully.

And also, I need to reset the old selection, do I have any choice?