# Different performance of ListView in Android 4.4.4 and Android 4.2.2, how to remain the same?

Tags: android, listview, focus, selector

Just now, I find that the same `selector` have different performance:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

For a view as follow:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu                  |    Content                                                 |
|This is a ListView     |    This is a ListView                                      |
|                       |                                                            |
| Menu 1                |    Content 1                                               |
| Menu 2                |    Content 2                                               |
| Menu 3                |    Content 3                                               |
| Menu 4                |    Content 4                                               |
|                       |    Content 5                                               |
|                       |    Content 6                                               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When you use `direction key` in remote control(so I am developing a android project in TV), the focus change from Menu to Content:

**In Android 4.4.4 platform:**
the selected menu(for example `Menu 1`) keep `black`, the selected Content(for example `Content 1`) change from `white` to `black`.**updated: In other words, the `Menu` item stay selected when switch to `Content` view**

**In Android 4.2.2 platform:**
All Menu change to `white`, the selected Content change from `white` to `black`

How can I keep the same in two platforms? I prefer the performance in Android 4.4.2 platform.

Comment: by performance , you mean behavior ?

Comment: @Hacketo by performance, I just want to say they show different in different platform. I just didn't find a accurate word.

Comment: So the problem is that the first listView has an item that stay selected when you switch to the second listView ?

Comment: @Hacketo yes, it is exactly the problem.

Comment: So you could use listView1.clearChoices() when you click on a item of the second listView

Comment: @Hacketo No, I tried this in `OnFocusChangeListener`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67464/discussion-between-roger-and-hacketo).